# Web Deploy - ERROR_COULD_NOT_CONNECT_TO_REMOTESVC

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2012, webdeploy

My web deploy from visual studio has died.

Message in Visual Studio:

```
Error   8   Web deployment task failed. (Could not connect to the remote computer ("server.cloudapp.net") using the specified process ("Web Management Service") because the server did not respond. Make sure that the process ("Web Management Service") is started on the remote computer.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_COULD_NOT_CONNECT_TO_REMOTESVC.)      0   0   Website(2)
```

Message in IIS Logs

```
    #Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 7.5
    #Version: 1.0
    #Date: 2015-07-29 16:00:35
    #Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
    2015-07-29 16:00:35 100.65.156.xx HEAD /msdeploy.axd site=#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 7.5
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2015-07-29 16:00:35
#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
2015-07-29 16:00:35 100.65.156.xx HEAD /msdeploy.axd site=MySite 8172 WebDeployUser 98.100.99.xx - 401 1 1326 1656
2015-07-29 16:00:35 100.65.156.xx HEAD /msdeploy.axd site=MySite 8172 WebDeployUser 98.100.99.xx - 401 1 1326 578
2015-07-29 16:01:42 100.65.156.xx HEAD /msdeploy.axd site=MySite 8172 WebDeployUser 98.100.99.xx - 200 0 0 546
2015-07-29 16:01:42 100.65.156.xx HEAD /msdeploy.axd site=MySite 8172 WebDeployUser 98.100.99.xx - 200 0 0 62
2015-07-29 16:01:55 100.65.156.xx POST /msdeploy.axd site=MySite 8172 WebDeployUser 98.100.99.xx VS12.0:PublishDialog:WTE12.5.60612.0;sid=9d3cf0e6-4187-4b82-bc75-4521d013cba7;op=Sync 200 0 0 12296
2015-07-29 16:01:55 100.65.156.xx POST /msdeploy.axd site=MySite 8172 WebDeployUser 98.100.99.xx - 200 0 0 13015
2015-07-29 16:01:56 100.65.156.xx HEAD /msdeploy.axd site=MySite 8172 WebDeployUser 98.100.99.xx - 200 0 0 62
2015-07-29 16:02:01 100.65.156.xx POST /msdeploy.axd site=MySite 8172 WebDeployUser 98.100.99.xx VS12.0:PublishDialog:WTE12.5.60612.0;sid=9d3cf0e6-4187-4b82-bc75-4521d013cba7;op=Sync 200 0 0 4374
2015-07-29 16:02:01 100.65.156.xx POST /msdeploy.axd site=MySite 8172 WebDeployUser 98.100.99.xx - 200 0 0 5109
2015-07-29 16:05:22 100.65.156.xx HEAD /msdeploy.axd site=MySite 8172 WebDeployUser 98.100.99.xx - 200 0 0 62
2015-07-29 16:05:22 100.65.156.xx HEAD /msdeploy.axd site=MySite 8172 WebDeployUser 98.100.99.xx - 200 0 0 93
2015-07-29 16:05:55 100.65.156.xx POST /msdeploy.axd site=MySite 8172 WebDeployUser 98.100.99.xx - 200 0 0 33547 8172 WebDeployUser 98.100.99.xx - 401 1 1326 1656
    2015-07-29 16:00:35 100.65.156.xx HEAD /msdeploy.axd site=#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 7.5
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2015-07-29 16:00:35
#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
2015-07-29 16:00:35 100.65.156.xx HEAD /msdeploy.axd site=MySite 8172 WebDeployUser 98.100.99.xx - 401 1 1326 1656
2015-07-29 16:00:35 100.65.156.xx HEAD /msdeploy.axd site=MySite 8172 WebDeployUser 98.100.99.xx - 401 1 1326 578
2015-07-29 16:01:42 100.65.156.xx HEAD /msdeploy.axd site=MySite 8172 WebDeployUser 98.100.99.xx - 200 0 0 546
2015-07-29 16:01:42 100.65.156.xx HEAD /msdeploy.axd site=MySite 8172 WebDeployUser 98.100.99.xx - 200 0 0 62
2015-07-29 16:01:55 100.65.156.xx POST /msdeploy.axd site=MySite 8172 WebDeployUser 98.100.99.xx VS12.0:PublishDialog:WTE12.5.60612.0;sid=9d3cf0e6-4187-4b82-bc75-4521d013cba7;op=Sync 200 0 0 12296
2015-07-29 16:01:55 100.65.156.xx POST /msdeploy.axd site=MySite 8172 WebDeployUser 98.100.99.xx - 200 0 0 13015
2015-07-29 16:01:56 100.65.156.xx HEAD /msdeploy.axd site=MySite 8172 WebDeployUser 98.100.99.xx - 200 0 0 62
2015-07-29 16:02:01 100.65.156.xx POST /msdeploy.axd site=MySite 8172 WebDeployUser 98.100.99.xx VS12.0:PublishDialog:WTE12.5.60612.0;sid=9d3cf0e6-4187-4b82-bc75-4521d013cba7;op=Sync 200 0 0 4374
2015-07-29 16:02:01 100.65.156.xx POST /msdeploy.axd site=MySite 8172 WebDeployUser 98.100.99.xx - 200 0 0 5109
2015-07-29 16:05:22 100.65.156.xx HEAD /msdeploy.axd site=MySite 8172 WebDeployUser 98.100.99.xx - 200 0 0 62
2015-07-29 16:05:22 100.65.156.xx HEAD /msdeploy.axd site=MySite 8172 WebDeployUser 98.100.99.xx - 200 0 0 93
2015-07-29 16:05:55 100.65.156.xx POST /msdeploy.axd site=MySite 8172 WebDeployUser 98.100.99.xx - 200 0 0 33547 8172 site=MySite 98.100.99.xx - 401 1 1326 578
2015-07-29 16:01:42 100.65.156.xx HEAD /msdeploy.axd site=MySite 8172 WebDeployUser 98.100.99.xx - 200 0 0 546
2015-07-29 16:01:42 100.65.156.xx HEAD /msdeploy.axd site=MySite 8172 WebDeployUser 98.100.99.xx - 200 0 0 62
2015-07-29 16:01:55 100.65.156.xx POST /msdeploy.axd site=MySite 8172 WebDeployUser 98.100.99.xx VS12.0:PublishDialog:WTE12.5.60612.0;sid=9d3cf0e6-4187-4b82-bc75-4521d013cba7;op=Sync 200 0 0 12296
2015-07-29 16:01:55 100.65.156.xx POST /msdeploy.axd site=MySite 8172 WebDeployUser 98.100.99.xx - 200 0 0 13015
2015-07-29 16:01:56 100.65.156.xx HEAD /msdeploy.axd site=MySite 8172 WebDeployUser 98.100.99.xx - 200 0 0 62
2015-07-29 16:02:01 100.65.156.xx POST /msdeploy.axd site=MySite 8172 WebDeployUser 98.100.99.xx VS12.0:PublishDialog:WTE12.5.60612.0;sid=9d3cf0e6-4187-4b82-bc75-4521d013cba7;op=Sync 200 0 0 4374
2015-07-29 16:02:01 100.65.156.xx POST /msdeploy.axd site=MySite 8172 WebDeployUser 98.100.99.xx - 200 0 0 5109
2015-07-29 16:05:22 100.65.156.xx HEAD /msdeploy.axd site=MySite 8172 WebDeployUser 98.100.99.xx - 200 0 0 62
2015-07-29 16:05:22 100.65.156.xx HEAD /msdeploy.axd site=MySite 8172 WebDeployUser 98.100.99.xx - 200 0 0 93
2015-07-29 16:05:55 100.65.156.xx POST /msdeploy.axd site=MySite 8172 WebDeployUser 98.100.99.xx - 200 0 0 33547
```

Message in Event Viewer

```
ERROR_SERIALIZER_ALREADY_DISPOSED - An error occurred on a callback thread. These errors are usually benign and are handled automatically. The details are below: 
System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a closed Stream.
   at System.IO.BufferedStream.Write(Byte[] array, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter.Flush(Boolean flushStream, Boolean flushEncoder)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextWriter.Flush()
   at Microsoft.Web.Deployment.TraceEventStreamSerializer.WriteKeepAliveEvent()
```

Turned on failed request tracing, but nothing is showing up there

Other things I've checked

- Ports are open in the firewall
- The World Wide Web Publishing Service, Web Deployment Agent Service, and Web Management Services are running
- There aren't any pieces of the web deploy software that weren't installed.
- Pointing ProcMon at my websites folder doesn't show any read/write errors
- The validate and preview steps always work ok in visual studio, it's the actual deploy that fails.
- Web Deploy seems to work for some sites and not others. Not sure what the pattern is.

The server is a VM in azure and running windows server 2008 R2 Datacenter with SP1.

Any ideas?

Comment: The traffic is being blocked for some reason. My best guess is that it is firewall related. Assuming that you had to create/edit rules for the deployment service in the machine(s). I've never tried Azure, but in windows, in the firewall rule, on the tab "Advanced", is the rule enabled for the "Public" profile?

Comment: @rll Ya, I think the windows firewall side is squared away. I've tried turning it off before but didn't seem to make a difference.